# What were Zabuza's political objectives in staging a coup?

Tags: naruto

It stated in early *Naruto* that Zabuza attempted a coup in the Hidden Mist Village, but failed. This is interesting due to information disclosed much later in the series, mainly that

> with his Sharingan, Tobi was manipulating the Mizukage.

However, the series gives us only occasional tidbits about the Hidden Mist Village's history. Is Zabuza's motivation for staging a coup ever explained in any of the various media? Did he know about Tobi and have a problem with that? Did he just dislike some policies the Mizukage was doing? Or did he want some particular policies? Was it just a power grab?

Answer (score -1):

Zabuza used to be one of the 7 legendary swordsmen of mist. He was loyal with their kage until he got to know about their dark intentions to misuse them. He was patriotic to his nation and this revelation made him furious, due to which he planned to coup. Coming to Tobi, he met Tobi disguised as Madara and he had no problem as he didn't knew Tobi. He also ignored Tobi on his words. He only wanted to serve his land for its betterment until his last breath.